# How can I send an analog signal through an HDMI port?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, conversion, vga, cable

Last week I bought an HDMI to VGA cable (with no power port) from china, it didn't work and my VGA monitor says no signal.

Many people say that it is fake, and someone on this forum says that you need to convert the digital HDMI port to analog signal: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/43547-42-hdmi-cable.

What can I do?

Comment: HDMI is digital and VGA is analog.  You can get a converter that will transform the computer's HDMI output into a VGA signal for the monitor.  A simple cable with an HDMI connector at one end and a VGA connector at the other is a scam.

Comment: Either a scam or just simply **not meant to be used for that purpose**. A HDMI connector at one end and a "VGA-connector" (15 pin high density D-SUB) at the other end is a totally valid cable, **BUT NOT for this purpose though**.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=active+HDMI+to+VGA is what you want.

Comment: Just an FYI, converting HDMI to VGA is finicky _(or maybe it's VGA to HDMI)_, even with converters from well-known, large cable manufacturers, and is not guaranteed to work with all systems and monitors.

Answer (score 2):

The cable is most likely faulty. HDMI to VGA cables are very common, and contain the circuitry (powered from the HDMI cable) to convert digital to analog. It could be fake, but as these cables are fairly cheap anyway it's probably not.

Answer (score -1):

Davidgo's answer is completely wrong. The cable in question is one of the junk passive cables that could never transmit an analog signal, not an active adapter (that would contain the circuitry to convert digital to analog) like davidgo is talking about.

To correctly answer your question, the cable is junk and should never have been made by the manufacturer in the first place. It absolutely is a fake, and would never work because HDMI can't transmit an analog(VGA) signal. HDMI only transmits digital signals.

The cable isn't faulty. The problem is that, fundamentally speaking, (in regards to video signals) the cable you bought would never work from the beginning.